# error en mi terminal Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'

Tags: angular

[image: Mensaje en la terminal]Hola a todos tengo un problema con **NgModel** a pesar de la  su importacion **FormsModule** en app.module la verdad no se de donde proviene el error. Es como si no reconociera el NgModel a pesar de la importacion. He **reiniciado el servidor de angular** varias veces y cerrado **Vscode**  y el problema persiste.  aqui le deja una muestra de mis archivos para ver si me pueden dar una mano

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

// Importation pour faire petitions Http
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';


import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';


import { FooterComponent } from './footer/footer.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AdmindiplomeComponent } from './admin/admindiplome/admindiplome.component';
import { AdminnavbarComponent } from './admin/adminnavbar/adminnavbar.component';
import { AdminprojetsComponent } from './admin/adminprojets/adminprojets.component';


@NgModule( {
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    AdmindiplomeComponent,
    AdminnavbarComponent,
    AdminprojetsComponent,
    FooterComponent,

  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
} )
export class AppModule { }
```

```
    <div class="container mt-5 py-5 " style="width: 50%;">
    <div class="card ">
        <div class="card-header text-center bg-dark text-white "> {{ title }} </div>
        <div class="card-body ">
            <form (ngSubmit)="create()">
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="nomDiplome" class="col-2 col-form-label">Dîplome</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nomDiplome" id="nomDiplome" placeholder=" Master 2" autofocus [(ngModel)]="diplome.nomDiplome">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group row ">
                    <label for="ecole" class="col-form-label col-sm-2"> Ecole</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8 ">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="ecole" placeholder="Université de Lille" id="ecole" [(ngModel)]="diplome.ecole">
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="ville" class="col-form-label col-sm-2"> Ville</label>

                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="ville" placeholder="Lille" id="ville" [(ngModel)]="diplome.ville">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row ">
                    <label for="description" class="col-form-label col-sm-2 py-5 mt-5"> Description</label>

                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <textarea name="message" cols="30" rows="10" maxlength="1000" placeholder="Message... " class="form-control" name="description" id="description" [(ngModel)]="diplome.description"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label class="col-2 col-form-label">&nbsp;</label>
                    <div class="input-group col-md-8">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-block">Enregistrer</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
export class Diplome {
  id: number;
  nomDiplome: string;
  ecole: string;
  ville: string;
  description: string;
  annee: string;
```

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Diplome } from 'src/app/model/diplome';


@Component( {
  selector: 'app-creatediplome',
  templateUrl: './creatediplome.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./creatediplome.component.css']
} )
export class CreatediplomeComponent implements OnInit {


  title: string = "Créer un Dîplome";
  public diplome: Diplome = new Diplome();
  erreurs: string[];
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit (): void {
  }


  public create (): void {
    console.log( "hello depuis create" );
    console.log( this.diplome );


  }


}
```

ya probe tambien inlcuyendo **ReactiveFormsModule**.

la verdad no veo de donde provenga el problema  les agradezco por su ayuda

Comment: El componente `CreatediplomeComponent` No está en el arreglo de declaraciones del `app.module` por esa razón no tiene acceso al NgModel.

Comment: hey gracias por tu ayuda eso era el error